# ImageView of Cards in a deck

Tags: java, arrays, android-studio, arraylist, imageview

I am working on a game with cards (not "52 card deck"). You have to choose 10 cards for your deck from a `DeckChooseFragment`. Thats working fine (chosen cards are stored in an `ArrayList` called `Deck`).

In another `Fragment` `DeckFragment` I want those 10 chosen cards to be displayed. I have Images for each card. In `DeckFragment` I have 10 `ImageViews`.

What do I have to do, that in `DeckFragment` only those 10 cards are displayed in my `ImageViews`?

The cards are referred to as "1; 2; 3; 4; etc." in `Deck`.

Answer (score 0):

Before opening the `DeckFragment` put the list of card ids into a `Bundle` and provide it via the `arguments` property:

```
DeckFragment().apply {
    arguments = bundleOf("cardIds" to "1; 2; 3; 4;")
}
// open the fragment afterwards
```

Then in the DeckFragment:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    arguments?.getString("cardIds")?.let {
        // load the list of images based on the given ids
    }
}
```